# PSQL - INSERT has more expressions than target columns

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, psql

when I try to insert something to my PSQL DB i get this error:

> SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: INSERT has more expressions
>   than target columns LINE 1: ...acturer, model, submodel) VALUES($1,
>   $2, $3, $4, $4, $5, $6) ^

My query is displayed below, to avoid that its somehow data problem I just insert number strings. So this looks really wired for me.

Query:

```
public function insertToPsql($manufacturer_code, $main_type, $subtype_code, $manufacturer, $model, $submodel)
{
    try {
        //$con = new PDO( PSQL_DB_HOST, PSQL_DB_HOST, PSQL_DB_HOST );
        $con = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=audahistory;host=localhost", "postgres", "");
        $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $sql = "INSERT INTO car_type(manufacturer_code, main_type, subtype_code, manufacturer, model, submodel) VALUES(:manufacturer_code, :main_type, :subtype_code, :manufacturer, :model, :submodel)";
        $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bindValue( 'manufacturer_code', "1", PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindValue( 'main_type', "2", PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindValue( 'subtype_code', "3", PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindValue( 'manufacturer', "4", PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindValue( 'model', "5", PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindValue( 'submodel', "6", PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    catch( PDOException $e ) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
}
```

Any idea where cna be a problem?
Thanks for advise

Comment: In your insert into SQL line, you have :manufacturer listed twice.

Comment: Thank you @P.Gearman i changed that but it looks problem is still there :(

I also try something really simple from terminal, will add edit in a minute

Comment: Show your `DB` table.

Comment: @Andurit Not that is matters, but I notice you are inserting numbers as strings. Are the values just placeholders? Also, you are declaring the data type being submitted, do they match the data types of the columns? Could we get your table structure to cross reference with.

Comment: `$4` is twice in `...$3, $4, $4, $5...`. it does not look that this comes from the query shown in the question.